# UserAuthorities in Basic Auth with Spring Security for REST API

Tags: java, spring, rest, security, authorization

I have been trying to secure my Spring Rest API with Basic Auth using Spring Security. I want it to be configured so that users are stored in a database and that they have access to different endpoints depending on their role. 
For simplicity, in the below example all endpoints require "ADMIN" role. 
I think I configured everything correctly (based on some online tutorials), however it seems like Security cannot deal with comparing my UserAuthorities (roles).
When I send a GET request through postman and authorize with a username and password, my user is found (I do not get a 401), but I get a 403, as if the user did not have proper role. If I change `(hasRole(Role.ADMIN.name()) to authenticated()` it works great. Can you please take a look at my code and help me figure out what I am missing?
User class:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Set<UserAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<UserAuthority>();

    public User(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void addAuthority(UserAuthority authority) {
        authorities.add(authority);
    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setAuthorities(Set<UserAuthority> authorities) {
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }
}
```

UserAuthority class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "authorities")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserAuthority implements GrantedAuthority {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public UserAuthority(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAuthority() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        UserAuthority authority = (UserAuthority) o;

        return name != null ? name.equals(authority.name) : authority.name == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0;
    }
}
```

Security configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static String REALM = "MY_TEST_REALM";
    //to be a bean later
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new StandardPasswordEncoder();
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").hasRole(Role.ADMIN.name())
                .and().httpBasic().realmName(REALM).authenticationEntryPoint(getBasicAuthEntryPoint())
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);//We don't need sessions to be created.
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint getBasicAuthEntryPoint() {
        return new CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint();
    }

    /* To allow Pre-flight [OPTIONS] request from browser */
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
    }
}
```

Important part of UserServiceImpl class:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserAuthorityRepository userAuthorityRepository;
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new StandardPasswordEncoder();

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return userRepository.getUserByUserName(s);
    }
}
```

The response I get is 403: The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.

`userRepository.getUserByUserName(s)` returns me a proper `User` object with the correct authorities.

I am sorry that there is so much code, I just do not have a clue where the mistake might possibly be..
Thank you very much for your help!
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it! Turns out the roles have to be persisted with a prefix "ROLE_", so I added this to my Role enum:

```
private static final String ROLE_PREFIX = "ROLE_";

public String nameWithPrefix() {
    return ROLE_PREFIX + name();
}
```

Now it works :)